# Multiple = alignment

Tags: align

I'm trying to align the `=` of the *third* line with the `second =` of the *second* line. I've tried several combinations with no pleasing result. There are numerous 'alignment' questions and answers but none seem to fit this (trivial?) situation.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\text{Then } x &= a_0y \text{ for some } y \in D\\
&= a_0uy = a_0yu\\
&= xu
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: double_equal]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\text{Then } x &= a_0y \text{ for some } y \in D\\
&= a_0uy \begin{aligned}[t]
           & = a_0yu\\
           & = xu
         \end{aligned}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see... a `double` alignment! Thx! Btw, can you briefly say what the `{alignedat}[t]{1}` does ?

Comment: @AthenaWidget `alignedat` does the same as `alignat`, except that it is not a display environment but creates a table like `tabular` and `array`, which can be used anywhere in math mode. The `[t]` option does the same as for `tabular` and `array`: It aligns `alignedat` with its first line (**t**op).

Comment: Great!! Would you say this is then effectively the same as the `array` approach suggested by Zarko? i.e the `{alignedat}[t]{1}` does the table creation for us? (Sorry I'm still a bit green;)

Comment: What's the difference between `alignedat{1}` and an ordinary `aligned` with a single `&`?

Comment: @Bernard Well, is there a difference? I haven't looked at the implementation, but probably not.

Comment: @gernot: I don't think there's one. It's just lighter to use `aligned`…

Comment: @AthenaWidget The difference between `array` and `alignedat`/`aligned` is the spacing of the columns and rows. If you write `x&=ay` or `x&=&ay` in an array environment, it will be spaced unevenly or too wide; with extra tweaking you can use it as well.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the comment, I changed it.

Comment: @AthenaWidget Anyway, even though you now have two or three solutions to choose from, I'm not sure that this is the best way of structuring the equation. I'd choose something more linear, using one or at most two lines. E.g. inline: `Then, for some $y\in D$, we have $x=a_0y=...=xu$. Or: `Since $x=a_0y$ for some $y\in D$, we have $x=...$`. The best choice depends on where the argument is heading.

Comment: @gernot Let me consider that. The only hesitation is that in the entire project, the condition, such as, `for some` etc appears after the introduction, `x=a_0y`. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

with array (simple and effective):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\begin{array}{rll}
\text{Then } x  & = a_0y  & \text{for some } y \in D\\
                & = a_0uy & = a_0yu\\
                &         & = xu
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
considering *Sigur* coment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\begin{array}{rlcl}
\text{Then } x  & = a_0y  &   &\text{for some } y \in D\\
                & = a_0uy & = &a_0yu\\
                &         & = &xu
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was trying so hard to use this approach, but I could not get it to work. Thx!

Comment: Since the space before `for` is not the default, I'd align it above `a_0`.

Comment: @Sigur Great suggestion! Done in reality.

Comment: @AthenaWidget, as you see, array works and it is not so hard :)