# Alignment within cases

Tags: horizontal-alignment, cases

I'm trying to align the `if`'s in the following MWE, but also keep the `(n times)` alignment intact. Applying the mechanism from [Multiple = alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365312/multiple-alignment) and from [Aligning conditions in cases environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41422/aligning-conditions-in-cases-environment), I still could not get it to work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    ns = 
\begin{cases}
   \quad s + s + ... + s  & \text{ (n times) if } n > 0 \\ 
   \quad\quad\quad 0 & \text{ if } n = 0  \\
   \quad (-s) + (-s) + ...+ (-s)  & \text{ (n times) if }  n < 0 
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Incidentally is there a way to remove the hideous `\quad`'s ? (Does one question per question apply here?:)

[image: Cases]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\hphantom` in the second line to move the text over, or alternatively `\hfill`, as Mico mentions in a comment.

What's the purpose of the `\quad`s anyway?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}    
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    ns = 
\begin{cases}
    s + s + \dots + s  & \text{ ($n$ times) if } n > 0 \\ 
   0 & \text{\hphantom{ ($n$ times)} if } n = 0  \\
   (-s) + (-s) + \dots + (-s)  & \text{ ($n$ times) if }  n < 0 
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to change the alignment for the columns in `cases`, one possibility is to define a new environment with the help of `mathtools`, as described in [Right aligned first column in a cases environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27520/right-aligned-first-column-in-a-cases-environment) For example, to have the first column centered, and the second right aligned :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\newcases{crcases}{\quad}{%
  \hfil$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$\hfil}{\hfil$\m@th\displaystyle{##}$}{\lbrace}{.}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    ns = 
\begin{crcases}
    s + s + \dots + s  & \text{ ($n$ times) if } n > 0 \\ 
   0 & \text{ if } n = 0  \\
   (-s) + (-s) + \dots + (-s)  & \text{ ($n$ times) if }  n < 0 
\end{crcases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\quad`'s were to align the 0 near the center of the equations above and below.

Comment: `...` should be `\dots`

Comment: In your first example, consider writing `\hfill \text{if $n = 0$}` instead of `\text{\hphantom{ ($n$ times)} if } n = 0`.

Answer (score 8):

With `aligned` (from `amsmath` package):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
ns = \left\{\begin{aligned}\quad
   & s + s + \dotsm + s             & \text{ ($n$ times) if } n & > 0   \\
   & 0                              & \text{ if } n             & = 0   \\
   & (-s) + (-s) + \dotsm + (-s)    & \text{ ($n$ times) if } n & < 0
     \end{aligned}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 but I would say that `\quad` is excessively large.  Also the `n` inside `\text` need to be in math mode.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, quad is left from OP MWE, I will reduce this distance. Similarly about n, I will correct this too.

Answer (score 5):

There should be a wider separation from “(*n* times)” to “if” than from the formulas and “(*n* times)”, in my opinion.

The 0 should be left flush, like the other two terms. I also fixed the math error (it should be |*n*| in the third line).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
ns =
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
&s + s + \dots + s          &\quad \text{($n$ times)}   &\qquad& \text{if $n > 0$} \\
&0                          &\quad                      &\qquad& \text{if $n = 0$} \\
&(-s) + (-s) + \dots + (-s) &\quad \text{($|n|$ times)} &\qquad& \text{if $n < 0$}
\end{alignedat}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

And with simple `array`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}    
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
ns = \left \{
\begin{array}{lrl}
   s + s + \dots + s          & (n \text{ times})   & \text{ if } n > 0 \\ 
   0                          &                     & \text{ if } n = 0  \\
   (-s) + (-s) + \dots + (-s) & (|n| \text{ times}) & \text{ if } n < 0
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\right.` Very clever! It makes this mechanism very powerful.

Answer (score 3):

With `empheq`, `eqparbox` and `alignat*, which allows for several alignment points, and full control on the spacing between columns. I also propose another layout (better in my opinion) which requires only`cases`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{empheq}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand\eqmathbox[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$ \displaystyle#2 $}}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left = {ns=\empheqlbrace\,}]{alignat*=2}
  &\eqmathbox{s + s + \dots + s} & \text{ (n times) } & \text{if } n > 0 \\
   & \eqmathbox{0} & & \text{if } n = 0 \\
    & (-s) + (-s) + \dots+ (-s) & \qquad\text{ (n times) } & \text{if } n < 0
\end{empheq}

\begin{equation*}
    ns =
\begin{cases}
   \eqmathbox[C]{\,s + s + \dots + s} \text{\quad (n times)} & \text{ if } n > 0 \\
    \eqmathbox[C]{\,0} & \text{ if } n = 0 \\
   \, (-s) + (-s) + \dots + (-s) \text{\quad (n times)} & \text{ if } n < 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]